# sqlite3: Non-aligned pointer being freed on iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

I get these sqlite3 crashes that are driving me nuts. Perhaps it is something obvious I am missing?
Example (from iOS 6 simulator):

```
MyApp(14195,0xb0115000) malloc: *** error for object 0xffffffff: Non-aligned pointer being freed
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
(lldb) bt
* thread #13: tid = 0x2d03, 0x94bd8875 libsystem_c.dylib`malloc_error_break, stop reason = breakpoint 2.1
frame #0: 0x94bd8875 libsystem_c.dylib`malloc_error_break
frame #1: 0x94be117a libsystem_c.dylib`szone_error + 270
frame #2: 0x94bdbc18 libsystem_c.dylib`szone_free + 232
frame #3: 0x02977221 libsqlite3.dylib`sqlite3MemFree + 33
frame #4: 0x029420df libsqlite3.dylib`sqlite3DbFree + 127
frame #5: 0x02980a7c libsqlite3.dylib`sqlite3SrcListDelete + 60
frame #6: 0x029b2ba1 libsqlite3.dylib`sqlite3FkCheck + 1425
frame #7: 0x029bde60 libsqlite3.dylib`sqlite3GenerateRowDelete + 608
frame #8: 0x02993cb1 libsqlite3.dylib`sqlite3DeleteFrom + 2177
frame #9: 0x02983786 libsqlite3.dylib`yy_reduce + 11030
frame #10: 0x02980535 libsqlite3.dylib`sqlite3Parser + 245
frame #11: 0x02947458 libsqlite3.dylib`sqlite3RunParser + 312
frame #12: 0x029c6137 libsqlite3.dylib`sqlite3Prepare + 695
frame #13: 0x0294664e libsqlite3.dylib`sqlite3LockAndPrepare + 270
frame #14: 0x02946735 libsqlite3.dylib`sqlite3_prepare_v2 + 53
frame #15: 0x002610f6 MyApp`-[MySqlDB prepare:](self=0x0b1abc90, _cmd=0x005694fc, sql=0x0057b1a5) + 294 at MySqlDB.m:123
```

I have added a breakpoint to malloc_error_break.
Now, let's go to the MySqlDB prepare: function:

```
- (BOOL)prepare:(const char*)sql
{

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    statement = nil;
    return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

And the caller function is:

```
- (BOOL)deleteWithID:(NSInteger)theID {
    BOOL theResult;
const char *theQuery = "DELETE FROM addresses WHERE id = ?;";
    if ((theResult = [impl prepare:theQuery]))  // CALLER HERE
    {
    [impl setInt:theID forIndex:1];
    [impl step];
    }
[impl finalize_statement];


    return theResult;
}
```

Any ideas? If I actually run sqlite on that same database file and try to execute the delete statement with the sane value (4 in the above case), the statement executes fine.

Ok, I ran again (and also enabled malloc diagnostics, guard) and this time it managed to crash on the [impl step] line on the same function above (which simply calls sqlite3_step(statement)):

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #12: tid = 0x2b03, 0x029e493b libsqlite3.dylib`allocateCursor + 139, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x715e6f40)
frame #0: 0x029e493b libsqlite3.dylib`allocateCursor + 139
frame #1: 0x029dd3d4 libsqlite3.dylib`sqlite3VdbeExec + 35684
frame #2: 0x0294fbc1 libsqlite3.dylib`sqlite3_step + 3169
frame #3: 0x00261398 MyApp`-[MySqlDB step](self=0x25409fe0, _cmd=0x043a9897) + 120 at MySqlDB.m:169
frame #4: 0x0018aeb0 MyApp`-[MyDataBase deleteWithID:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, ok, I think I solved it with a mutex lock. After using @synchronized for the DELETE I can't seem to reproduce the problem. However I had checked the rest of the threads during those crashes and none of the other threads was doing anything db related, so am not sure how it was crashing. Any ideas esp. how to debug such issues in the future are welcome!

Comment: I already wrote my db tasks in @synchronized block still gettings same error. Any idea? how to solve this?